# Resizing choropleth datamaps into container in datamaps

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

I am trying to create a dashbord and I have used choropleth datamap which I got from [here](http://datamaps.github.io/).

My problem is that when I try to resize the datamap graph to fit into my container,it is not getting scaled properly.

So how to scale the map,to a container of

```
width=100% and height = 450px.
```

hope you can help me out here

Comment: can you put this up on a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use d3 to get the size of the container:

```
var containerw = d3.select(".containerclass").style("width');
var containerh = d3.select(".containerclass").style("height');
```

Now use those values on your svg:

```
var map = d3.select('.containerclass').append("svg").attr('class','map');

map.style('width',parseInt(containerw) + 'px').style('height',parseInt(containerh) + 'px');
```

Comment: R user, JS beginner here -- where should I place this code inside the `<script></script>`? As another user mentioned above, it'd be great to see this answer on `jsfiddle`. Thank you.